# Is javascript alert() not secure?

Tags: javascript, security, web, browser

I read a book about JavaScript security and the book says using `alert()` function on web application development is not secure.

I couldn't find any reason about this in the book.

Why `alert()` is not secure?

Comment: I believe the security issue is referring to infinite alert as the window alert box will block all user operation of browser until user clicked on "OK".  User will not be able to close the browser normally if there is an infinite alert. Some older version of IE will block alert box by default.

Comment: Have you got any reference or exact quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is why but alert() is a function on the global scope and is easily accessible and can be overwritten. In one of my more desperate attempts to do some debugging once I neutered it and confirm() to keep alerts from popping up on screen while looking for a bug.

```
window.alert = function(msg){
    console.log(msg); 
}

window.confirm = function(msg){
    console.log(msg); 
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: *Every* function can be overwritten in js with enough effort.

Comment: Very true, everything can be overwritten/read regardless of how deep or obfuscated it is in JavaScript/HTML the only thing you can do is make it harder. Some people don't realize that these built in functions aren't actually special and are just functions on the global scope.

Comment: Point is that, by over-riding this global function, no one can hack the system

Answer (score 1):

This is a **FALSE** statement. `Alert` is just a basic function to communicate messages with the user in client-side. Unless something is submitted to the server and process over there, we don't need to worry about security. Even by over-riding this function, no one can hack anything. Happy `alert`ing !!

Comment: You don't need to worry about serverside security. Still, the client machine could be hacked/virus-infected etc if there was a hole in the function (unlikely) and at least the user can be annoyed by many alerts; you should worry about those.

Comment: @Bergi In this particular case, I am sure PO worries about using alert from a developer's point of view. That's why he posted the question in SO. It is developer's responsibility NOT to show infinite alerts. But alert function is innocent and harmless. What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add one more answer from an official source. In [Chromium policy on JavaScript dialogs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/dialogs-policy) they have stated that

> While window object named **alert(), confirm(), and prompt()** fit into
> the JavaScript of the time, their synchronous API is problematic for
> modern browsers. Because the JavaScript engine needs to pause until a
> user response is obtained, the JavaScript dialogs are app-modal. And
> because the dialogs are app-modal, they commonly (and unfortunately)
> are used to [harm our users](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/threat-analysis/2016/02/tech-support-scammers-use-new-browser-trick-to-defeat-blocking/).
>
> **Because of this, the Chromium team highly recommends that you not use JavaScript dialogs.**

Answer (score 0):

Only if you input sensitive information like some id or a key it could pose a problem else I don't see any issues. It is seen as a medium priority vulnerability by OSWAP but most of the time its false positive.

Answer (score -3):

As far as i know alert() can be used for Cross-site Scripting (XSS) attacks, but most of the web application firewalls are now equipped to detect those kind of attacks.

In my opinion not using alert() does not make our application secure. alert() is just one of the simple way to demonstrate an XSS attack. there are other ways like logging keystrokes, stealing session cookies etc.

This page explains XSS attacks in detail.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: How does `alert` enable XSS attacks?

Comment: Im not saying alert() enables xss attacks, but it can be used to demonstrate xss attack even though you cant much harm doing so. For example in the below post you can see under section "Blocking the Word “Script”" to see a demonstration of the same

https://www.securestate.com/blog/2012/01/30/web-application-firewall-does-not-equal-security

Comment: Well, every function can be used for demonstrations, but that doesn't make `alert` secure or not.